# jQuery AJAX converters jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, converters

I am trying to intercept an ajax jsonp response to do some response filtering.
My guess was, I could do this with custom converters. But the converter function is never run.
What am I missing?

```
var ajax_options = {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    url: url,
    data: parameters,
    success: success,
    converters: {
        "jsonp": function (raw) {
            console.log(raw);
            return raw;
        }
    }
};
$.ajax(ajax_options);
```

Thanks, McFarlane

Comment: I don't think that's the goal of [converters](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Converters) ("Generalized dataFilter callbacks that are called in response to a particular dataType being received that differs from what was expected"). Why not simply filter inside the success callback ?

Comment: because I want to intercept errors thrown by my API and I dont want to check it in every callback function I write but in general. dataFilter doesn't work with jsonp.

Comment: If it's any help, I use `converters: { 'text json': true } ` to send a json object and return an html response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now listened to common sense and decided to not misuse the poor converters.
I've created a solution using $.proxy() to intercept every JSONP response while keeping the correct context in the callback function.

Because my solution heavily depends on jQueryMX I won't paste my source here.

Comment: In the last two days I spent all time without figure out how to make it working.. Please can you help me do understand how it can be done? Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: it is important I really need it

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), converters are:

> A map of dataType-to-dataType converters. Each converter's value is a
>   function that returns the transformed value of the response.

Hence it's used to convert from one dataType to another.

Comment: so how do I use it then? I want to transform the response before returning it to the callback function

Comment: That depends on what you want to convert it to.

Comment: can't I "misuse" the converters to generally filter the raw api response? I see no other way to filter jsonp responses.